# Do you need a piercing mod equipped to shatter the Atlas Mech's canopy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've shot the canopy on the Atlas with the sniper rifle several times, and have not seen the canopy shatter.  Do you need a piercing mod attached to you weapons to shatter the canopy?

Comment: I've shattered the canopy with the Graal spike Launcher...

Comment: I've heard this is easier on harder difficulties, since they have more health, it might be a fixed, low chance that they shatter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no. all you need is a higher powered sniper rifle. 
here's a video: http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Atlas_Mech

Comment: I've been using the Black Widow.  I'll keep trying.