# How can I shatter the cockpit of an Atlas?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you need a piercing mod equipped to shatter the Atlas Mech's canopy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54547/do-you-need-a-piercing-mod-equipped-to-shatter-the-atlas-mechs-canopy)

I've seen a question about hijacking Atlas after the cockpit is shattered, and I've seen an in-game loading screen tip saying it can be done, but I have never managed to pull it off.

What are some strategies for increasing my chances that the cockpit shatters?

- I am playing on Insanity if it matters.
- I am a soldier and usually have disrupted ammo going for shields and incendiary ammo for armor.
- I've tried both assault rifle and pistol to no avail

I've seen [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53994/3062) but it doesn't really say how. Simply firing at the glass alone doesn't seem to be doing it for me. The Atlas always just seems to die without ever shattering.

Comment: Not sure if this counts as a duplicate, but it's very similar: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54547/14775

Comment: @Tristan I wish the accepted answer had more detail, but yeah, I agree, this is close enough to be a dupe.

Comment: If it's any consolation, two out of the three Me3 questions I've asked were duplicates. We've had so many so fast I can't keep track. Especially on the mobile site, where "similar" questions don't lost when you title your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the mass effect wiki:

"The Atlas' cockpit window can be shattered after its shields have been taken down. This requires a considerable amount of sustained fire, but breaking the window will leave the pilot vulnerable to attack. Killing the pilot will destroy the Atlas immediately in multiplayer. In some instances in single-player, however, this will leave the Atlas intact and able to be piloted by the player."

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Atlas

**Update**: IGN indicates that a sniper rifle is needed to accomplish the task. Video included.

http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Atlas_Mech

I suspect this may be because of the snipers accuracy so you don't hit other parts of the mech, and its power so it punches through quickly.

**Update 2**: My suspicion was right, they use the sniper for the power / accuracy. Other weapons do work however, I was able to smash the glass out with a pistol.

Comment: Can you give anymore detail? I've fired every single shot at the cockpit but it never seems to shatter for me.

Comment: I've yet to do it myself as I am focusing on Biotics, but IGN seems to think that a sniper rifle is needed. Includes a video:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Atlas_Mech

Comment: I've done it with a Graal Spike Thrower.